# Open ERP 6.1 add field inherited view

Tags: inheritance, xpath, odoo, odoo-view, openerp-6

I have a parent view id V which is a form F and inside this form a Goup with 3 fields F1, F2 and F3.

My inherited view looks like:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_v_form">
    <field name="name">My view</field>
    <field name="model">my.module.class</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="parent_module.V"/>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//form/field[@name='F3']" position="before">
            <field name="myField"/>
        </xpath> 
    </field>
</record>
```

But it doesn't appear anywhere, any idea?

Comment: If you show the original form it might help. Are you updating the module?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added `parent_module` to the `depends` attribute in the `__openerp__.py` file, and the xml file path to the `update_xml` attribute as well.

You don´t need to specify the form type and you don´t need to use the xpath neither:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_v_form">
    <field name="name">My view</field>
    <field name="model">my.module.class</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="parent_module.V"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="F3" position="before">
            <field name="myField"/>
        </field>
    </field>
</field>
```

Comment: both are there:         """,
        "depends" : ['my_parent_module'],
        "init_xml" : [ ],
        "demo_xml" : [ ],
        "update_xml" : [
                         'my_addon.xml',
                       ],
        "installable": True,
}. No way....